# Successfully Set up MythTv as PVR with EPG on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, mythtv

This is about the only reason I do not use Ubuntu as a full time OS. (Next PVR, and it's very good EPG)

My Question is has anyone successfully set up MythTv as a IPTV PVR (Loaded with a http://.m3u link that I subscribe to (contains login and password)) as a backend on Ubuntu 18.04? I get the program to run fine and it contains various card setups like IPTV, and others but none will load my channel list after I configure it. I'm using Version 29 Myth TV, fresh of their PPA Page. I have seen the Google Page that shows Network Setup (shown below) and has you input a link in the Card, but I do not have that option in my card setups.

[image]

This is all I could find and this Option is not Valid for Ubuntu 18.04 and Version 29 MythTv (latest)..

BTW my EPG is a .xml file if anyone has info where that goes...Haven't made it that far...yet :(

Comment: Yes, I have Posted on Myth TV Forum, Just looking for other "possible" solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In mythtv-setup for IPTV one can select IPTV recorder as TV-card, and configure it with the m3u URL.
Once you have done that, you have to configure a Video Source. There you choose a 'grabber', which is the mythtv equivalent of the epg source. With my fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 and a recent Mythtv, the choices in the grabbers are meager.

To get some more xmltv-grabbers, see: https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/XMLTV#Introduction

After installing the additional grabbers, you can select the one you like in mythtv-setup. That one needs some configuration too, just selecting it will not do. The configuration is a bit tedious, for every channel you have to choose to include it or not. But after including some of them, entering 'none' will exclude the rest. Then run mythfilldatabase and see what happens.

I hope this helps (a bit).

Comment: I have moved on to XTeve. Much more user friendly! Thanks! https://xteve.de/

Comment: Xteve works with any player that will play m3u's not just Plex.